# Displaying just the files with correct extension

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel

I'm trying in QFileSystemModel display just files with extention `*.txt` and the other types shaded/grayed out:

- `proxy_` is of type QSortFilterProxyModel
- `model_` is of type QFileSystemModel

Here's my code:

```
proxy_->setFilterWildcard("*.txt");  
proxy_->setSourceModel(model_);
model_->setNameFilters(QStringList(proxy_->filterRegExp().pattern()));
model_->setNameFilterDisables(true);
sel_model_ = (new QItemSelectionModel(proxy_));
treeView->setModel(proxy_);
treeView->setSelectionModel(sel_model_);
```

...but by doing so nothing is shown in my view. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you setting the root path or directory for `model_`? Otherwise there are no files to filter on. Should look something like this: `model_->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a file name filter with `QFileSystemModel::setNameFilters`.

In the example program below `.txt` and folders are displayed normally, and other files are disabled (greyed out).

The `nameFilterDisables` property allows you to choose between filtered out files being disabled or hidden.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFileSystemModel model;
    model.setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());

    QStringList filters;
    filters << "*.txt";

    model.setNameFilters(filters);

    QTreeView view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```